# java web localization support

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, localization

i have already created localized .properties files. but i have no idea how to change them on the fly. Thing is i can make a form selector for language but where should i point the output to set? It always uses the default .properties file

my form looks like this

```
<h:form>
<h:selectOneMenu id="language" value="????">
  <f:selectItem id="item1" itemLabel="Czech" itemValue="cs_CZ" />
  <f:selectItem id="item2" itemLabel="Slovak" itemValue="sk_SK" />
  <f:selectItem id="item3" itemLabel="English" itemValue="default" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
</h:form>
```

i am using spring with hibernate JSF2.0 and J2EE1.6

Thanks

UPDATE:

i loaded the bundle like:

```
 <f:loadBundle basename="bundle/labels" var="labels"/>
```

but i need to replace it with:

```
<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basenames">
                <list>
                    <value>Messages</value>
                    <value>labels</value>
                </list>
            </property>
</bean>
```

but this solutions wont find the labels.properties in package bundle. it looks for in classpath but i cant relocate it.

UPDATE 2:

ok now i can see JSF and SPRING has different loading methods, while SPRING takes bundles from messageSource JSF still takes them from `<f:loadBundle>` so how do i make `<f:loadBundle>` to take translated properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring Support this with a [`LocalChangeInterceptor`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/i18n/LocaleChangeInterceptor.html). This interceptor can be configured to an property it is listen to.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor"
          p:paramName="lang" />
<mvc:interceptors>
```

Then you need to send HTTP Requests with parameter `lang=cs_CZ`

@See [Spring Reference Chapter 15.6.4 LocaleChangeInterceptor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#mvc-localeresolver-interceptor) for more details

Comment: ok i have added the interceptor problem now lies in here: i have `<f:loadBundle basename="bundle/labels" var="labels"/>` but i need to replace it with `<bean id="messageSource"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <property name="basenames">
                <list>
                    <value>Messages</value>
                    <value>labels</value>
                </list>
            </property>
        </bean>` but it wont find my labels.properties in package bundle

Comment: Sorry, I did not recognized that you are using JSF.